# Is there anyway to develop a gui using HTML,CSS,JavaScript and use java for the backend?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, user-interface

I'm building a point of sale system of my senior capstone and I really don't have much knowledge on building GUIs in java but I have made many UIs using HTML, CSS, and javascript. Just wondering if there is a way to combine the two.

Comment: yes, it is possible, just google more about it. you can do it with C# too, using MVC and visual studio, that already have many options to use those languages

Comment: read about [Servlets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) , It is what you are searching for

Comment: Use Spring Boot with Java. You can construct a RESTful service in a few minutes

Comment: If you know JS, why not consider Node and Express?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a desktop app, JavaFX uses CSS and XML for GUI, you could give it a shot! You can also use JavaFX scene builder to make the view building simpler.